# how to extract numbers in string in c?

Tags: string, numbers

i have a string. so i want to extract "27" in "Delay:27m",
how could i do this?
i'm gonna extract "27" and show that in 7segment.
i have a code with for like this:

```
#include <mega32.h>
#include <delay.h>

unsigned char i,j,j2;
char x[50];
char str[50]="Speed=120K Delay=27 Hum=30% Time=12:20";

void main(void)
{
DDRA  = 0xFF;  // for 7seg
PORTA = 0x00;

while (1)
      {
      for (i=0;i<50;i++)
      {
          x[i]=str[i];
          if (x[i] == "D")
          {
              i++;
              x[i]=str[i];
              if (x[i] == "e")
              {
              j=1;
              j2=i+5;
              x2[j]=str[j2];
              t1[1]=x2[j];
              j++;
              x2[j]=str[j2];
              t2=x2[j];
              }
          }
      }

      PORTA=x2;
      delay_ms(2000);
      }
}
```